# Run external jenkinsfile in another jenkinsfile

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

let's say I have 'global' Jenkinsfile stored in separated git repo where I've defined all possible stages that any of my pipelines might want to use. Some of those steps are inside if statement to give possibility to skip them if needed. 
Is there any chance to in my project create dedicated Jenkinsfile that include this global jenkinsfile and pass some parameter?

Thanks from advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The possibility to call certain kind of methods in your pipeline is delivered by [JenkinsSharedLibrary](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/). So the best way to do these conditional pipelinesteps would be to define your stages in Closures and then call these Closures as required in your Jenkinsfile.

Example Closure defined in your Shared Library:

```
//Closure which defines Groovy or Jenkins Pipeline DSL to be executed
Closure javaBuildStage = {
  stage('Build Java') {
    echo "This is the build stage for Java apps"
    sh("./mvn clean package")
  }
}
```

Example Jenkinsfile:

```
@Library('YourSharedLibrary@master')
if(project == "java"){
  javaBuildStage()
}
```

You can decentralize all your functions with the Jenkins Shared Libraries. The Jenkins Shared Libararies will be located in a Git Repository.

Answer (score 0):

For triggering same Jenkins file for all repositories, you can use Remote File Plugin.
For details you can check this answer
https://stackoverflow.com/a/58877133/6110485