# Jenkins: is there a simple way to trigger jenkins job when a specific file is modified in enterprise github?

Tags: jenkins, github

Is there a simple way to trigger jenkins job when a specific file is modified in enterprise github?

For example:

```
github: https://example.git.lab.com
repo: testrepo
```

If a file named *base.cfg* in the repo is changed, then a Jenkins freestyle job in Jenkins is triggered and executed. Thanks.

I checked git and github plugin, but didn't find they have this functionality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your Jenkins freestyle job configuration page:

1. Under **Source Code Management**, select **Git**.
2. Specify the repository URL, credentials, and branch.
3. Next to **Additional Behaviours**, click **Add** and then select **Polling ignores commits in certain paths**.
4. In the **Included Regions** textbox, specify the filepath relative to the root of the repository. You can specify multiple filepaths or regex patterns in new lines.
5. Save the changes.

Assuming that you have already [configured Gitlab webhooks](https://github.com/jenkinsci/gitlab-plugin#webhook-url), this job will be triggered only when the specified file(s) have been updated. The other files in the repository will be ignored.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Dibakar Aditya for your detailed guide. I will try the solution later.